# Need help understanding where MySQL deadlocks

Tags: mysql, deadlock

We have a long standing problem with a certain deadlock in our DB. The conflicting queries are almost always these two:

```
UPDATE db.tbl 
    SET pid = 68111
WHERE pid IS NULL 
AND processed IS NULL 
AND `time` <= now() 
LIMIT 10
```

and

```
UPDATE `db`.`tbl` 
    SET `processed` = -1,
        `updated_on` = NOW() 
WHERE (`tbl`.`id` = 108588129)
```

The `pid`, `id` and `processed` values vary, but the queries are the same.

What I don't understand is what exactly could deadlock there, since the second query updates a specific record by its ID. There's just one lock to be had, but you need at least 2 to create a deadlock. There are also no transactions that would lock other rows - each of these queries is standalone.

Why is this happening and how could I avoid it?

Anonymized/shortened output of `show engine status innodb;`:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-06-08 08:16:27 0x7f70f3ef1700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2857804352, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2480 lock struct(s), heap size 286928, 9581 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 25966272, OS thread handle 140144661681920, query id 847014117 x.x.x.x db_user updating
UPDATE db.tbl SET pid = ''68111'' WHERE pid IS NULL AND processed IS NULL AND `time` <= now() LIMIT 10

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 2714 page no 86552 n bits 1552 index processed of table `db`.`tbl` trx id 2857804352 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: SQL NULL;
 1: len 4; hex 8678cf9b; asc  x  ;;

Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: SQL NULL;
 1: len 4; hex 8678cfad; asc  x  ;;

<Snip a lot of Record Locks just like the one above>

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2714 page no 113955 n bits 160 index PRIMARY of table `db`.`tbl` trx id 2857804352 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 92 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8678ec61; asc  x a;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000aa56a25d; asc    V ];;
 2: len 7; hex 0100002bc01686; asc    +   ;;
 3: len 4; hex 803ff583; asc  ?  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 73746f70; asc stop;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 6: len 1; hex 83; asc  ;;
 7: len 4; hex 80005737; asc   W7;;
 8: len 6; hex 4b4a38363431; asc KJ8641;;
 9: len 8; hex 80000008a515e59b; asc         ;;
 10: len 4; hex 800001be; asc     ;;
 11: len 5; hex 99b050b41a; asc   P  ;;
 12: len 4; hex 84ad8892; asc     ;;
 13: len 3; hex 736d73; asc sms;;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: SQL NULL;
 16: len 1; hex 7f; asc  ;;
 17: SQL NULL;
 18: SQL NULL;
 19: SQL NULL;
 20: len 4; hex 53746f70; asc Stop;;
 21: len 5; hex 99b050b41b; asc   P  ;;
 22: len 5; hex 99b050b41b; asc   P  ;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2857804381, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 25966282, OS thread handle 140122483259136, query id 847014368 x.x.x.x other_db_user updating
UPDATE `db`.`tbl` SET `processed` = ''-1'', `updated_on` = NOW() WHERE (`tbl`.`id` = 108588129)

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 2714 page no 113955 n bits 160 index PRIMARY of table `db`.`tbl` trx id 2857804381 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 92 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8678ec61; asc  x a;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000aa56a25d; asc    V ];;
 2: len 7; hex 0100002bc01686; asc    +   ;;
 3: len 4; hex 803ff583; asc  ?  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 73746f70; asc stop;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 6: len 1; hex 83; asc  ;;
 7: len 4; hex 80005737; asc   W7;;
 8: len 6; hex 4b4a38363431; asc KJ8641;;
 9: len 8; hex 80000008a515e59b; asc         ;;
 10: len 4; hex 800001be; asc     ;;
 11: len 5; hex 99b050b41a; asc   P  ;;
 12: len 4; hex 84ad8892; asc     ;;
 13: len 3; hex 736d73; asc sms;;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: SQL NULL;
 16: len 1; hex 7f; asc  ;;
 17: SQL NULL;
 18: SQL NULL;
 19: SQL NULL;
 20: len 4; hex 53746f70; asc Stop;;
 21: len 5; hex 99b050b41b; asc   P  ;;
 22: len 5; hex 99b050b41b; asc   P  ;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2714 page no 86552 n bits 1552 index processed of table `db`.`tbl` trx id 2857804381 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 1462 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: SQL NULL;
 1: len 4; hex 8678ec61; asc  x a;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Also, a simplified table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,

  `other` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_other` (`other`),
  KEY `ix_processed` (`processed`),
  KEY `ix_time` (`time`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I should also note that there are many rows (currently over 5000, but the number constantly varies during the day) with `processed=null, pid=null` but `time` in the future.

**Added:** A bit more context, as per comments:

There are currently a little over 5 million rows in this table. It's a sort of a queue and we get roughly 1.4M rows per month. The earliest rows are in February. When `time` is in the future, it's almost always in the same day.

`pid` and `processed` are related to the queue. When a row (job) is inserted, both `pid` and `processed` are `null`. `time` is when the job should be performed (some jobs need to be performed only AFTER a specified moment in time; others need to be performed ASAP).

When one of the processors is ready to execute some jobs, it starts by running the first query and "reserving" a batch of 10 jobs for itself by settings its PID (Linux process ID) to those rows. It then selects those rows and works through them one-by-one, setting the `processed` flag when it's done (the second query).

However sometimes those two queries clash and we get a deadlock.

Comment: Do you really have 2 quotes around `''68111''` or is that an edit issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly - That's in the `show engine innodb status;` output, but I'm sure it's some sort of formatting issue. I can remove it, I suppose.

Comment: So how many rows in this table?

Comment: So could you not amend the (do 10) update so that it updates the row using the `id` I assume you must have it from when you grab the 10 rows of things to do!

Comment: Or use an `IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` at least to save it having to troll the whole table

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I'm sorry, I don't follow. The `update ... limit 10` _is_ the grabbing. This is what reserves the rows so that other processors don't take them. What isn't shown here is the next query: `select * from tbl where pid=1234 and processed is null;` - this actually selects the data of the 10 rows that we just grabbed.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - That is, this process is run in multiple instances so that there are multiple processors that churn through the jobs in parallel. The whole `pid` thing is so that two processors don't start executing the same job in parallel.

Comment: And the reason for grabbing 10 things to do?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Optimization, I guess. I didn't write that code. My guess is that it cuts down on the number of `update ... limit X` queries needed.

Comment: Do you have any stats on how long that first work grabbing query takes? maybe an execution plan as well

Comment: Ok, how about this. The "work grabbing" update will run for some time and traverse and LOCK a number of pages on that table. That adds to the likelyhood of the other query clashing. If you changed the code to do a `SELECT id ... LIMIT 10` and then a seperate UPDATE to grab those items of work using a `UPDATE .... WHERE id IN(1,2,3...)` that would be much quicker and lock possibly only 10 pages of the table but only for a **much shorter time**.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - That... is a pretty neat idea! I like that!

Comment: Phew! Was not sure you were prepared to make code changes. Do let me know how it turns out

Comment: Actually that is going to leave a space for 2 job grabbers to get the same job. You may need to do a `select id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE` -> `UPDATE` in a for 10 loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly - no, a `for update` is just as bad as the `update` I'm already doing. It takes the same locks and thus has the same problems. What I intend to do is to first `select...limit 10` and then... well, the processor as it is, currently sets `processed=-1` when it starts to process, and `processed=1` when it's done. I just change that first `update`  to read `update ... set processed=-1, pid=1234 where pid is null and id=1`. Then I check the count of updated rows to see if it succeeded. If it did, I continue. If not, skip the row and continue with the next.

Comment: But you are only doing it for ONE row, if necessary do it in a transaction and commit after each iteration of the loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can even increase that first SELECT to get more than 10 rows. And at no point will there be a ranged update (all updates will be by ID), and there will be no chance of two processors clashing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly What's the problem with doing it for only 1 row?

Comment: No Problem, I think we are confusing each other now :)

Comment: Ah, my point was that as you do your first `Select 10` another Job Getter could be doing the same thing and get one or more of the same rows.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Yes, of course. But that's handled afterwards. :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Anyways, while I'm positive that this workaround will work, perhaps you can also figure out what exactly happened in the original query? How does a deadlock form there?

Comment: Innodb locks the rows it needs to scan, not just the row that satisfies the where criteria. So, if you do not have proper indexes supporting the where clauses, the queries may end up locking a lot more rows than you expect.

Comment: @Shadow I'm not sure it's that simple. The second query was an update by ID. It literally locks just one row. There's no possibility of a deadlock there unless there's something else going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest updating your update

```
UPDATE db.tbl 
    SET pid = 68111
WHERE pid IS NULL 
AND processed IS NULL 
AND `time` <= now() 
LIMIT 10
```

To an update where ID IN (select).  At least my thinking about it. The update is locking while it is trying to gather and figure out what it SHOULD update.  By pre-querying what you want as a select, and updating based on those IDs, the Select does not lock, finishes getting the few records it needs, then applies the update to them by their key ID.

So the time index is used first for the select (should be fast), then the update is done based on the PKID returned from the select.  Something like

```
UPDATE db.tbl 
   SET pid = 68111
   WHERE id in ( select t2.id
                    from db.tbl t2
                    where t2.time <= now()
                      and t2.pid is null
                      and t2.processed is null 
                    limit 10 )
```

Now to optimize the Select query, I would have a single index to include the parts it needs without having to go to the raw data pages.  So instead of your index on just the TIME column, I would have an index on

```
(time, pid, processed, id )
```

So the entire where is qualified, but also has the ID for returning the outer update WHERE ID IN condition.

Comment: This is the workaround I intend to implement, yes. We discussed it with @RiggsFolly in the comments. I'm still wondering just how a deadlock can arise in this situation, since the other query is updating only one record by its ID.

Comment: This will lead to `Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`. You need to wrap it in another `select` and access it as a derived table - `id in ( select id from ( your select ) x )`. I don't think that index would be used, due to the range predicate for `time`.

Comment: This trick may work:  `WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM ( SELECT t2.id ... LIMIT 10 ))`

Answer (score 1):

I have a very limited understanding of locking and deadlocks, so this is over-simplified, as I am not sure "which lock is requested when" (initial secondary index scan, PRIMARY and then other secondary indices impacted by update?) by the *main* `UPDATE` query:

1. Session 1 sends the initial `UPDATE` query, chooses the `ix_processed` index as the most selective, and starts locking the index *rows*, until it has gathered enough rows to satisfy the query.
2. Session 2 sends the `UPDATE on PK` query which immediately gets the x-lock on *row* in the clustered index.
3. Session 2 tries to apply the update to `processed` column which requires x-lock on `ix_processed` but it is already locked by Session 1, so it waits.
4. Session 1 tries to get the x-lock on the clustered index for rows gathered in `1.`, but the row being updated is locked by Session 2 (`2.`), so it waits.
5. deadlock

---

Your current `UPDATE` requires a lot more locks than you might think.

When using the repeatable-read isolation level (`select @@session.tx_isolation`), which is the default, the exclusive lock will be placed on every row examined for the UPDATE, not just those that are updated.

You can test this with something like:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE tbl 
    SET pid = 68111
WHERE pid IS NULL 
AND processed IS NULL 
AND `time` <= now() 
LIMIT 10;

SELECT dl.object_name, dl.index_name, dl.lock_type, dl.lock_mode, dl.lock_status, dl.lock_data, tbl.*
FROM performance_schema.data_locks dl
JOIN performance_schema.threads t ON dl.THREAD_ID = t.THREAD_ID
JOIN tbl ON tbl.id = dl.lock_data
WHERE dl.object_name = 'tbl'
AND dl.index_name = 'PRIMARY'
AND t.PROCESSLIST_ID = CONNECTION_ID();

ROLLBACK;
```

Adding a composite index on `(processed, pid, time)` will reduce the number of locks required for the `UPDATE` statement to just 10.

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD INDEX ix_processed_pid_time (processed, pid, time);
```

If you do not want to add the index, then you could try setting a distinct value for the `processed` column (-2 maybe) in the `UPDATE`, as this would mean it is immediately excluded from subsequent updates.

If you are using MySQL 8, another approach might be to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE pid IS NULL AND processed IS NULL AND `time` <= NOW()
LIMIT 10
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

UPDATE tbl
    SET pid = 68111,
        processed = -2
WHERE id IN ( ... );

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

"... Understanding ..."

Without a suitable index (see user1191247 answer), too many rows will be locked, leading to a deadlock.

If you have a recent version of MySQL, `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...` will provide more information about what index is being used.

(I doubt if using a subquery will help.)